# Why is my "Else" not working in my batch file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement

This should be simple but it's really confusing me at the moment and I can't figure out why. I am reading a URL from a text file in the same location as the batch file but I can't get the part "Else (ECHO DOMAIN)" to work. The (ECHO DOMAIN and GROUP) works however.

The URL in the "Upgrade.txt" is provided to me in the format of:
* CLIENT01 - NAME OF CLENT (Live) Site URL (https://address1.ourdomain.co.uk)

This is the batch file I can't get to work:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
PUSHD "%~dp0"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=/." %%d IN (Upgrade.txt) do (
        SET "Domain=%%d"
    )

for /f "tokens=4 delims=/)" %%g IN (Upgrade.txt) do (
    SET "Group=%%g"
    IF "!Group!" NEQ "" (ECHO DOMAIN and GROUP) ELSE (ECHO DOMAIN)  
)

ECHO Domain=!Domain!
ECHO Group=!Group!

PAUSE
```

Running it gets me the result

> Domain=address1 
>   Group=

but is should be:

> DOMAIN 
>   Domain=address1 
>   Group=

However if I change the URL in the "Upgrade.txt" to this format of:
* CLIENT01 - NAME OF CLENT (Live) Site URL (https://address1.ourdomain.co.uk/address2)
Running it gets me the correct result of:

> DOMAIN and GROUP 
>   Domain=address1 
>   Group=address2

Why is the `"Else (ECHO DOMAIN)"` not being printed and both ECHO's are ignored completely? (The Echo's will be replaced with commands so I need to know each part is being called correctly and the Echos at the bottom are just to prove to myself what the values are so I know what action should be called)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,4 delims=/)" %%f IN (Upgrade.txt) do (
```

Since the data does not produce a `%%g` (the fourth token) then the `for` does execute the code for that line. Fix it by selecting another token that will exist as `%%f` then `%%g` will be empty.

BTW -

```
SET "Group=%%g"
IF "!Group!" NEQ "" (ECHO DOMAIN and GROUP) ELSE (ECHO DOMAIN)
```

could be

```
IF "%%g" NEQ "" (ECHO DOMAIN and GROUP) ELSE (ECHO DOMAIN)
```

or

```
SET "Group=%%g"
IF not defined Group (ECHO DOMAIN and GROUP) ELSE (ECHO DOMAIN)
```

but even better

```
IF "%%g" EQU "" (ECHO DOMAIN) ELSE (ECHO DOMAIN and GROUP)
```

to eliminate the double-negative.

Comment: Unfortunately all 3 suggestions do not work for this example, I set "Group=%%g" as I would use that later on in the batch file so needed that to be set but working with just the %%g for testing still didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Yes I read that as in it wouldn't pick up the token, which I knew, tried it with the %%f (but in the 'DO' section) in the example and it didn't work but I just notied thats because I needed to change it just before the 'DO' section which is as I expected now, many thanks :) apologies for not getting that correct the first time